# How can I get the number of pages in a PDF file inside a Google Apps Script?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

The PDF files are in my Google Drive. I just got that I can get the number of pages of a PDF sending it as a job to Cloud Print, because Cloud Print will return a JSON object with "numberOfPages" attribute.

Is there any faster and easier way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this ? If yes, can you please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually did like I said.

I take my file, then send it to CloudPrint via its JSON Api. I need to send it to a dummy printer, a printer I registered in CloudPrint but actually is never connected to Internet. Then, I get the number of pages of the PDF file in the value of response's "numberOfPages" attribute. Save this number in some var. Finally, I send a delete petition to JSON Api for my file in the dummy printer, indeed isn't necessary at all.

Thanks!